# Connect IdentityServer4 with external authentication

Tags: identityserver4, google-authentication

I wonder how to wire the connection myself between IdentityServer and an external authentication providers (e.g. Google)? I think this is given when using IdentityServer4 QuickStart UI with implicit grant; e.g. the external log in trigger is wired already.
But I am using **Resource owner password grant** so that I can use my own log in UI and can't figure out how to connect IS and external authentication.
I tried to add Google and then go to `localhost:5001/signin-google` but got an error. I think I need more setup but unsure how. Has anyone done this?
I also registered `localhost:5001/signin-google` in the google console for authrorized origin.

This is my config:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = _authority;
                    options.ApiName = "my-api";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    //options.ApiSecret = "secret";
                    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both;
                });

            // add google
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ClientId = "b5lge4nj8djnr63lm25rbl4nl0gct73v.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "vfRXJmEXnKuIsSnHxOn_f";

                });
```

This is the log:

```
2017-12-30 21:43:50.641 +00:00 [INF] Error from RemoteAuthentication: The oauth state was missing or invalid..
2017-12-30 21:43:50.646 +00:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.<HandleRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
2017-12-30 22:00:38.055 +00:00 [INF] Error from RemoteAuthentication: The oauth state was missing or invalid..
2017-12-30 22:00:38.079 +00:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.<HandleRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

**Update1**: When I add `CallbackPath`, `localhost:5001/signin-google` returns 404 Not Found now.

```
// add google
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ClientId = "b5lge4nj8djnr63lm25rbl4nl0gct73v.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "vfRXJmEXnKuIsSnHxOn_f";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/home";
                });
```

Comment: A bit late, but wouldn't you need `options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google"` instead of `options.CallbackPath = "/home"`?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If yes then could you please share solution?

Comment: @shobhitvaish sorry didn't manage to get this working; after reading a bit more online, a lot of people don't recommend using Resource owner password grant.